# How to Get the code from a client .jar version

Tags: java, jar

I just joined an enterprise as JAVA programmer, here it has a .jar sent to the client with folders with libs and resources, but I can't find the base code used to form this .jar. I there anyway from the .jar sent to the client to get the base code or just some classes to re-write the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JDGUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) to decompile the .jar into many .java.

1. Open the .jar with the JDGUI
2. The program will decompile all the .class into .java
3. Then, you can export all the .java into some folder

Answer (score 0):

You can decompile the *.class in the jar (using for example http://jd.benow.ca/) but you'll not be able to retrieve the javadoc or the assembly configuration.

Best is still to ask whoever gave you this jar to provide it with the source code...

Comment: The problem is that the one who made it got fired and deleted the code

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but I with the hints here i almost got a new one over, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

The [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) Java decompiler works pretty well for me, and is pretty handy when you want to quickly look up some implementation of a 3rd-party method.

I primarily use this method to check for performance problems when calling  3rd-party libs, so it is ok for this purpose, but it is certainly not a substitute for having the original, fully documented source code, as well as the original developer to ask questions.

Please note that a decompiler will not be of much use if the .jar has been obfuscated, prior to packaging.